# Error: Missing comma in a FORMAT statement

Tags: fortran, gfortran, fortran77

My codes are written below:

```
DIMENSION T(10)
DATA A,B /9.,5./
IS=1
J=J+3
T(j-2)=A
T(J-1)=A-B
80 T(J)=T(1)+T(J-1)
J=J+1
IF(J.NE.10) GOTO 80
DO I=1,5
WRITE (*,15) I, T(J)
END DO
15 FORMAT ('T('I2')=', F8.4)
STOP
END
```

My compiling error is written below:

```
jdoodle.f95:13:16:

 15 FORMAT ('T('IS')=', F8.4)
                1
Error: GNU Extension: Missing comma at (1)
jdoodle.f95:11:20:

 WRITE (*,15) I, T(J)
                    1
Error: FORMAT label 15 at (1) not defined
```

Could you please tell me where is the false statement of my Fortran code? The result must be T(1)=nnn.0nnn I think.

Comment: try `('T(',I2,')=',F8.4)`  The second error just follows because the labeled format was invalid

Comment: Thank you very much! It worked, but results are only zeros??

Comment: `j` is never initialized. Try `j=3` instead of `j=j+3`

Comment: If it is your new code for learning, I strongly recommend you to learn something from this century. Say Fortran 95 or even more recent. The style from your code is very hard to read and not at all recommandable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you very much, I've just found a solution!

The code is:

```
DIMENSION T(10)
DATA A,B /9.,5./
IS=1
J=J+3
T(J-2)=A
T(J-1)=A-B
80 T(J)=T(1)+T(J-1)
J=J+1
IF(J.NE.10) GOTO 80
DO I=1,5
WRITE (*,15) I, T(I)
END DO
15 FORMAT ('T(',I2,')=',F8.4)
STOP
END
```

The result is:

```
T( 1)=  9.0000
T( 2)=  4.0000
T( 3)= 13.0000
T( 4)= 22.0000
T( 5)= 31.0000
```

Thank you.

Comment: since you posted as an answer , please see my comment about initializing `j`  This will bite you if you ever change compilers.

Answer (score 4):

As can be seen, replacing the format specification with

```
15 FORMAT ('T(',I2,')=',F8.4)
```

stops the compiler complaining.  I'll answer more generally now.

A format specification can be made up of multiple format items where each item is an edit descriptor or (recursively) a parenthesized list of format items.

It is usually necessary to separate each format item with a comma.  In the format of the question the edit descriptors are `'T('`, `I2` and `')='`.  [The first and last are character string edit descriptors and the second is a data edit descriptor.]  Neither comma between the two pairs is allowed to be omitted.

From the Fortran 2008 standard, the comma is allowed to be omitted only in the following cases:

- between a `P` edit descriptor and an immediately following `F`, `E`, `EN`, `ES`, `D`, or `G` edit descriptor, possibly preceded by a repeat specification;
- before a slash edit descriptor when the optional repeat specification does not appear;
- after a slash edit descriptor;
- before or after a colon edit descriptor.

Of course, just because such commas may be omitted that doesn't mean that they should be.  Having an optional comma present never hurts.

Further, as suggested by the compiler's message, a compiler may choose to accept the absence of commas even when a compliant program must have them (although the compiler must be able to detect such non-compliance).  As a personal statement I'd suggest avoiding such non-standard writing.

---

As has been noted in comments, even with the corrected format specification, the program is still not valid: having `j=j+3` before `j` is first defined is not allowed.